# Direct construction of Caratheodory Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a semi-field with its generating $\sigma$-field $\sigma \langle \mathscr{C} \rangle$. And let $\mathrm{P}$ be countably additive on $\mathscr{C}$. Then the Caratheodory extension theorem confirms that the outier measure
$$
    \mathrm{P}^{*}(A)=\inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{P} \left(C_{i}\right): C_{1}, C_{2}, \ldots \in \mathscr{C}, A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_{i}\right\}
$$
gives $\mathrm{P}^*$-measurable sets $\mathscr{A}^*$ forms a $\sigma$-field containing $\sigma \langle \mathscr{C} \rangle$. This further implies for any $A \subseteq \Omega$, there exists $B \in \sigma \langle \mathscr{C} \rangle$ such that $\mathrm{P}^* (A) = \mathrm{P}^* (B)$.

What I want to know the whether we can circumvent the Caratheodory Theorem, and for any $A \subseteq \Omega$, we can directly construct $B \supseteq A$ such that $\mathrm{P}^* (B) = \mathrm{P}^* (A)$? The biggest problem is how to make $B$ regardless of the specific form of $A$.